# SameTest for arrays of points

Tags: list-manipulation, geometry, gathering, distance

I need to gather arrays of points by some intuitive `SameTest`,
so for some tolerance the next arrays will be treated as the same:

[image]

Next code looks like suitable for it:

```
mySameTest[arr1_, arr2_, tol_] := 
  Length@arr1 == Length@arr2 && 
Max[EuclideanDistance[First@Nearest[arr1, #], #] & /@ arr2] < tol;
```

But I think it may be optimised. Moreover, for huge calculations I'd like to get a `Compiled` version of this function.
How to do it correctly?
Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: `ClusterClassify`? How the code work for the arrays in the picture? Maybe post an example.

Comment: Looks pretty good. To compile: `Compile[{{arr1, _Real, 2}, {arr2, _Real, 2}, tol}, 
 Length@arr1 == Length@arr2 && 
  Max[EuclideanDistance[First@Nearest[arr1, #], #] & /@ arr2] < tol]`